# What Data structure/Algorithm should I use - interview question

Tags: algorithm, oop

I was given this coding exercise in a job interview as follow-

we define direct relation between to people: Person A is directly related to person B if either their full name and/or address are equal (case sensitive).

we define n-level relation between person A and person B - if you can reach from person A to person B in exactly n direct relations.

I was asked to implement a utility with 2 fuinctions:

`void init(Person[] persons)` - initialization of the utility with the persons instances.

`int FindMinRelationLevel(Person personA, Person personB)` - returns the minimal level of relation between personA and personB. if they are not related - return -1.

They did not give me any limit for running time - can it be solved in linear time complexcity? 
The init function I thought about was running in O(n^2) for each person get all his 'neighbors' or something like that.

I was try to map all data with dictionaries, but got myself into a mess.
The classes that were given are:

```
class Person
{
    public Name FullName { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

class Name
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return FirstName + " " + LastName;
    }
}

class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Street + " " + City;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to see, with your definitions, how the n in the n-level relation could be anything other than 1 (directly related), or -1 (not related at all). I suspect your description is wrong: In the real world, two distinct people who share the same full name are usually _not_ related - anything else would be confusing.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError In the real world we often have records for the same person from multiple past places that they lived.  Assuming that "same full name, two addresses, is same person" is wrong at the current moment, but frequently right if you're looking in a database.

Comment: @btilly: There's no conflict between your statement and mine.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError JohnDoe at 1 Main st ~ JohnDoe at 1 Park st ~ SueSmith at 1 Park st

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I was pointing out how the definition could map with real world data to a question that a real world company might want the answer to.  Therefore the description as given is reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

I would use two maps of `String -> List<Person>`, one mapping each address to the list of people at that address, and one mapping each name to the list of people with that name.

This lets you `FindMinRelationLevel` using Breadth-First-Search algorithm in expected (because the maps and sets are probably hash tables) *O(N)* time.

Note that to achieve this time, you need to avoid revisiting name and address lists, in addition to avoiding revisiting persons.

Comment: Hi @Matt Timmermans. I can not see how your suggested solution covers relations that can be astablished by both Name and Address. As i anderstand you suggest to build 2 seperate data structures (for names and for adresses). For example how your suggestion get the connection between Ben and Adam in the following example?
{Ben Smith, Green Street NY}, {David Green, Green Street NY}, {David Green, Pacific Boulevard CA}, {Adam Levin, Pacific Boulevard CA}

The above is an example for 3-relation level.

Comment: The way i see it, your suggestion is creating a mapping of direct relations between Persons, and then use BFS.
How do i get the original object to start the search from (personA)?

Comment: `personA` is provided as a parameter to `FindMinRelationLevel`.  That *is* the original object, and you don't need to "get" it in any other way.  To do BFS, you put it in the queue, and then while there is a person in the queue, take it out, get his address and look up the list of address-related people in the map.  Then get his name and look up the list of name-related people in the other map.

Answer (score 1):

This is the [shortest path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path) in an undirected, unweighted [implicit graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_graph). You can solve it by [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) (BFS), although the BFS can be improved in the worst case.

To do the BFS efficiently, use a hashtable to look up people by name, and another hashtable to look them up by address. Building these hashtables takes O(n) time, and a standard BFS takes O(n + m) time where m is the number of edges (i.e the number of equal pairs of names plus the number of equal pairs of addresses).

Assuming there are unlikely to be many collisions, the above is good enough. If there are some very common names or addresses, then the worst case of the above is O(n<sup>2</sup>). We can do better, because once a name or address has been used to find the neighbours sharing that name/address, there is no need to use the same name/address to find neighbours of another person later. If we store the names/addresses that have been "used" so far in two hash-sets, then we only need to add "neighbours" to the BFS queue if the name/address they have in common is not already "used". This improves the overall time complexity to O(n).

Here's an example in Python:

```py
people = [
    ('John', '123 Fake st.'),
    ('John', '456 Fake st.'),
    ('Alice', '456 Fake st.'),
    ('Bob', '789 Fake st.'),
]

from collections import deque, defaultdict

def shortest_path(people, a, b):
    # build dictionaries in O(n) time
    names = defaultdict(list)
    addresses = defaultdict(list)
    for p in people:
        p_name, p_address = p
        names[p_name].append(p)
        addresses[p_address].append(p)

    # a has distance 0 to self
    queue = deque()
    queue.append( (a, 0) )

    visited = set()
    names_used = set()
    addresses_used = set()

    # loop iterates O(n) times, because each person can only be polled
    # twice from the queue, except a, who can be polled three times
    while queue:
        p, distance = queue.popleft()
        if p == b: return distance
        if p in visited: continue
        visited.add(p)

        p_name, p_address = p
        if p_name not in names_used:
            names_used.add(p_name)
            # each person can only be added to the queue once by name
            for q in names[p_name]:
                queue.append( (q, distance + 1) )
        if p_address not in addresses_used:
            addresses_used.add(p_address)
            # each person can only be added to the queue once by address
            for q in addresses[p_address]:
                queue.append( (q, distance + 1) )

    # b not found
    return -1
```